# Issue while building spring-framework source

Tags: spring, spring-framework-beans

I am facing some issue while building spring-framework source, what is the issue?

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

 Where:
   Build file '/home/steph/workspace_sts/spring-framework/spring-beans/spring-beans.gradle' line: 30

What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':spring-beans'.
> No such property: values for class: org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskDependency
  Possible solutions: values
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be saying that the class DefaultTaskDependency does not have a field and getter/setter called getValues()/setValues() but the gradle build file is passing in some data which it is trying to set by calling  setValues() and passing whatever data is in the gradle.build file under values. I would double check which version of gradle spring source says it needs to be built with vs. what version you are building it with.